# Extract a single character from a Fortran string

Tags: fortran

I need a program to convert from base a to base b, where base a and b could be from 2 to 36.

My idea was to use strings as the numbers, convert to base 10 as an intermediary and then convert from base 10 to base b. As I'm new on Fortran I can't understand quite the functions and substring, right now I'm getting the error:

```
intToChar  = cadena(int,int)
1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
```

On the next code:

```
CHARACTER FUNCTION intToChar(int)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: int
    CHARACTER(LEN = 36) :: cadena

    cadena = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

    intToChar    = cadena(int,int)
END FUNCTION intToChar
```

I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/fortran.html)

Comment: Notice that you don't really have to convert to *decimal* as intermediary step. You just convert to an integer value, which is internally stored in binary, though you don't really care: an integer has no inherent base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax to select a substring from a character variable uses a colon `:`, not a comma `,`.  The line the compiler is complaining about should be:

```
intToChar = cadena(int:int)
```

This will select the single character as position `int` from `cadena`, which appears to be your goal with that function.